# PHP mail function is not working bur sends no error in core php

Tags: php, email

I know , lot of questions here about my problem but I did not get the appropriate answer.
Here is a phpinfo of the link: "http://www.indusfloor.com.au:81/test.php"

and I am testing mail function to send the mail. sample code is-

```
if(mail($to, $sub, $msg, $header))
{ echo 'mail sent'; }
else 
   echo 'mail not sent';
```

I am getting the 'if condition' message but not the mail. I think if there is problem on the server's php file. That's why I have written the phpinfo file of site.

Thank You,

Comment: Please add `$header` content

Comment: you can add any mail address there, problem is- i am not getting any mail, you can write the above code in your first line of ur script, still is not working.

Comment: Please post your complete code including form

Answer (score 0):

You are using a windows server, and sendmail might not be configured well.

You may send mail using SMTP using PHPMailer Library.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: I have  used this page's code- 'PHPMailer/examples/smtp_no_auth.phps',  but when i used SMTP option mentioned here, I got SMTP connection error. After disabling this feature, I got same 'Message sent' but no mail,, :(

Comment: you need to create a mail account and use credentials in the configuration.